# Unable to copy input field value to another?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to copy one form `<input>` field value to another form using jQuery. Simple, right? Well I must be doing something wrong as my code isn't working. Here's what I've got:

HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
  <input id='one' type='text' />
  <input id='two' type='text' />
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <input id='three' type='text' />
</form>

<input type='button' id="do" value="Copy" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#do').click(function() {
  $('#3').html($('#1').html().val());
});
```

My overall goal is to get `3` to be populated with the value from `1` as soon as it's entered, which I can presumably do by binding it to `onBlur`.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Updated ID names as I wasn't using numbers (but realised that you can't/shouldn't) use numbers for HTML elements.

Comment: Warning: HTML ids should not be numeric.

Comment: @bfavaretto: *Should* not, but they work (at least in Firefox).  But I agree that using solely numbers for DOM ID's is a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry I'm actually not using numbers I just used this for illustrative purposes (but realised now that this is wrong!)

Comment: @Crontab, I know. Just to clarify: the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) forbids the use of numeric IDs. However, they seem to be valid according to the [HTML5 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
$('#do').click(function() {
  $('#3').val($('#1').val());
});
```

To update it constantly:

```
$('#1').keyup(function() {
  $('#3').val($(this).val());
});
```

Or, you can use blur to update when the user moves focus away:

```
$('#1').blur(function() {
  $('#3').val($(this).val());
});
```

I put these all on a jsfiddle so you can play around with what works best.

http://jsfiddle.net/cefpp/5/

Comment: Thanks for this, however, it doesn't put the value into the input box? Am I making sense here?

Comment: @Kiz It does for me...  What do you mean?

Comment: @Kiz I updated the link to the fiddle, please take a look now.

Comment: Just had a look at your fiddle and for me (no idea why), for the keypress example it doesn't populate the field with the copied value?

Comment: @Kiz I changed it to **keyup()**.  Does it still not work?  Are you on the newest version of the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/cefpp/5/

Comment: Working on the fiddle now - perfect thanks ! God knows what I was doing wrong :S

Comment: @Kiz Glad to hear it!  Now, go build the start of the next multi-billion dollar IPO!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#do').click( function(){
    $('#3').val( $('#1').val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#do').click(function() {
  $('#3').val($('#1').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IDs starting with a number are not allowed. Try using different IDs for your `input` elements.

You can also use the Console of Firebug or similar to check whether your selectors or certain functions are working. Also the console will output error messages, if something is wrong.

Comment: I'm actually not using numbers but I used this for illustrative purposes (bad example!) but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that help me

```
jQuery(".registration_mailingaddress_sep .city input").val(function(i,origText{
   return jQuery('.registration_address_sep .city input').val();
});
```